# Material UI Range Min Max Error: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Tags: reactjs, range, material-ui, focus, filtering

I'm new in React and in MaterialUI. I'm trying to make [range filter](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#range-slider) with min and max inputs and range line using MaterialUI and it example with [number-format](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries). 
If I use prop 'value' to Slider, when I try to move thumb, the error throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null.

But not all times. 
If I use prop 'defaultValue' there's no such error, but in console is another one:

> Material-UI: A component is changing the default value state of an
>   uncontrolled Slider after being initialized. To suppress this warning
>   opt to use a controlled Slider.

What should I do to make it work?
[Code in Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-range-errors-focus-czqx4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get rid of that warning do this:

```
setValues({
  ...values,
  [name]: Number(value)
});
```

the [API](https://material-ui.com/api/slider/) says it's expecting a `Number` but you are providing a string

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by this bug:

[[Slider] Cannot read property 'focus' of null at focusThumb #20896](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/20896)

I used `material-ui/core` verson 4.x but the bug is only fixed in version 5.

So I had to upgrade following the [migration guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/#mui-material-styles).